# Saving Identical email subjects but different threads

Tags: sharepoint-online

very new to SharePoint and have set up a team site, could I ask a quick hopefully simple question?

If I’ve got a document library and I drag emails into it with the same subject the library offers to replace the existing, which is fine in the case of a thread email. But what if it’s a different thread but with the same subject and you don’t want it to version it but be 2 .msg files?

Can you split them by adding a column based on the date sent/received or something?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

On a document Library can't be two files with the same name, it's behave like a PC folder. So it's necessary the two files have somehow different names.

If you need they have the same name and it's enough to achieve it on a certain view, you can use another column like `Title` and edit both to be the same. Then modify the default view to show just the Title instead the filename.

Local scripts or tool can be used to autorename files to make them unique using datetime or so.

[Incoming mail](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=incoming+mail) can be configured to Sharepoint directly import emails, that automatically deals with names, but then all mail are stored, not just the uploaded ones.

Comment: Thanks for response, but if site mail boxes have been deprecated where else/how can you import and to where? That’s why I’ve been trying to save them into a doc library and hence the problem arising